# Renews threshold is strange in spring eureka

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have 3 instances of my microservice in my program, and in the Eureka panel, Renews threshold and Renewes are equal to 6. Why is Renews threshold = 6? 3 * 2 * 0.85=5.1 means the ceiling is calculated? Now, when I close one of them and my program goes to self-preservation mode, after I opened the Eureka panel, Renews threshold=5 and Renews=4. My question is why Renews threshold = 5? Why did the floor considered this time? when I close another instance Renews threshold = 3. Why is this so?

2 instances:
[image]

1instance:
[image]